# Can I get elementary os freya on my raspberry pi 2 model B?

Tags: software-compatibility

I recently purchase a new Raspberry Pi 2 model B. I really liked the look of the elementary os freya, when I tried it in a vm. So, I wondered if I could install it onto my new Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 7):

The Elementary OS Freya cannot run on any of the current Raspberry Pis and their ARM-based processors. Right from their [blog](http://blog.elementary.io/post/137512265276/probing-to-verify-that-elementary-will-run-nicely):

> We don’t have official ARM builds at this time. However, our source code is available at launchpad.net/elementary and we welcome the community to work on a BeagleBone port if there is interest!

While answering a question about the beaglebone, the idea is the same: **no ARM port** as of now.

Noteworthy: There's a branch of [StackExchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/) for it.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot. The requirements for the OS are:

> Minimum System Requirements **1 GHz x86** processor 512MB of system memory
> (RAM) 5GB of disk space Graphics card and display capable of at least
> 1024x768 CD/DVD drive or ability to boot to a USB drive Users may be
> able to install Luna on devices that do not meet these requirements,
> but the experience is likely to suffer.
>
> System Recommendations 1 GHz
> x86 processor 1GB of system memory (RAM) 15 GB of disk space Graphics
> card and display capable of at least 1024x768 3D compositing CD/DVD
> Drive or ability to boot to a USB drive

The RPi 2 has a 900 MHz **arm7** processor, which is significantly different from the x86 architecture in the requirements above. It's kind of like giving instructions written in German to an English speaker. Sure, they may mean something, but they'd be unusable for me.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the most significant hurdle is the one made explicit in Ghanima's answer.  Even if you [overclocked the pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/41509/5538) to 1 GHz you still could not run an OS compiled for x86 processors.

Comment: @goldilocks: I thought I did...

Comment: True, but notice since the OP is presumably unfamiliar with the issue of processor architecture (which someone asking this question likely would be), this answer appeared to him to be primarily about the speed/memory stats.  If you didn't know the difference, would you notice "a 1 GHz *arm7* processor, let alone a 1 GHz *x86* processor"?